# How do I prove that EQTM ={<M1,M2>: L(M1) =L(M2)} is undecidable (assume that M1 and M2 are encodings of TMs)

Tags: turing-machines, undecidability

I am trying to revise for an exam, I have encountered this question and have seen an example solution, but it was provided by my lecturer, and it was fairly sparse and somewhat incomplete.

She jumps straight into a proof that has very little context, then ends it with "see Theorem 5.2" and that is why it is undecidable which is from a textbook none of the students actually purchased because we were told everything we need will be in the slides.

I know that I should approach this by using reduction, but from what I can barely understand this is a very basic reduction type proof, which I was hoping to understand to tackle harder questions.

If possible can this be explained to me in detail? Thanks.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the fact that it is undecidable whether a machine accepts the empty language, i.e., that $\{ M \mid L(M) = \emptyset \}$ is undecidable?

Comment: I am not entirely sure, is that just a known fact? Are you asking if the fact can be used in a proof? Or just by implying that fact alone is a proof in it of itself?

Comment: Well, the problem is not very hard, and it's an exercise, so a lot will depend on student's knowledge. For instance, I could just tell you "consider the case where $M_1$ accepts the empty language and $M_2$ is arbitrary", and that would be enough in some situations.